# Maximum size of empty UDP packet

Tags: udp

I want to stuff data into a packet, but I want to make sure that the packet does not exceed 512 bytes, so I need to know **what the initial size of a UDP packet is** so I know how much data I can put into the packet. I did some snooping around on Google, but I found answers that were contradictory. I'm using IPv6. Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Comment: Is your actual question what the minimum size of a UDP packet is? If so this has been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846077/size-of-empty-udp-and-tcp-packet) a few times. What's your reason for wanting to limit your packet size? 512 bytes is coincidentally the size imposed by DNS, have you [seen this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet) ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not start with the RFCs or Wikipedia:

- UDP: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol
- IPv6: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet

Result: 40 Byte for the minimal fixed IPv6 header and 8 byte for the UDP header

But: IPv6 has extension headers of variable length. Some of them can (theoetically) reach a length of 256 Bytes, so it's entirely possible to have a packet exceeding 512 byes without any payload.